# named scoped NOT IN, how to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, named-scope

how can I write a NOT IN in named scope syntax? For example, User :has_many Photos, how can I define:

```
User.has_no_photo
```

and returns all users who are not in the `Photo` model? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
named_scope :has_no_photos, :conditions => [ 
  "id NOT IN ?", 
  Photo.all(:select => "distinct user_id").map(&:user_id).map(&:to_i)
]
```

I assume you have a standard "Photo.belongs_to :user" association, and integer keys

Comment: This will give an error -- NoMethodError: undefined method 'user_id' for Fixnum. You probably meant to map `to_i` after `user_id` (or leave out the second map altogether...)

Comment: `"id NOT IN ?"` should be `"id NOT IN (?)"`

Answer (score 0):

ActiveRecord isn't different from what you would do in SQL:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :photos
  named_scope :has_no_photos,
    :conditions => "(SELECT COUNT(#{Photo.table_name}.*)
                     FROM #{Photo.table_name}
                     WHERE #{Photo.table_name}.user_id = #{User.table_name}.id) = 0"
end
```

There are probably more efficient ways of doing this. One would be to store the photos_count on the user rows: then the query becomes a simple photos_count = 0, instead of a complex join:

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, :counter_cache => true
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :photos
  named_scope :has_no_photos, :conditions => {:photos_count => 0}
end
```

Comment: bad example. counter caches are not guaranteed to be all time consistent

Comment: They're usually consistent enough for most purposes. It's your job as a dev to ensure they stay consistent.